# Is it possible to team multiple circuits in the current Tor network?

Tags: circuit, bandwidth

The client-selected paths that carry traffic through the Tor relay network are called circuits. Tor clients switch circuits at ten minute intervals for better anonymity. However, latency and bandwidth vary from circuit to circuit, based on the capabilities of the selected relays.

Connectivity and bandwidth are currently (especially with the millions of Mevade guests) too unreliable for such interesting applications as Tahoe-LAFS grids for online storage that's private, anonymous and fault-tolerant. That's especially problematic when mounting grid folders using fuse.

The capability to team multiple circuits would improve both reliability (through failover) and bandwidth. In [AlSabah et al. (2013) The Path Less Travelled: Overcoming Tor’s Bottlenecks with Traffic Splitting](http://freehaven.net/anonbib/#pets13-splitting), the authors "present Conflux, a dynamic traffic-splitting approach that assigns traffic to an overlay path based on its measured latency." They note that "it enhances the load-balancing properties of the network" and "significantly improves the experience of users who watch streaming videos online." They "also show that Conflux introduces only slight tradeoffs between users’ anonymity and performance."

What would it take to implement this in the current Tor network?

Comment: The answer to this question is either "yes" or "no."  The questions about implementation should be asked separately.

Comment: Sounds like you want http://freehaven.net/anonbib/#pets13-splitting

Comment: Are there any News? The Last Response is quite old..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now Tor has no support for splitting connections over different circuits.

While, technically, support could be added if we had a design and the manpower to implement it, it's at this time not entirely clear if it's a good idea.  The performance and anonymity implications have not been studied sufficiently.

Comment: Is it that [Johnson et al. (2013) Users Get Routed: Traffic Correlation on Tor by Realistic Adversaries](http://www.ohmygodel.com/publications/usersrouted-ccs13.pdf) has undermined the anonymity analysis in AlSabah et al. (2013)?

Comment: @mirimir: Not exactly undermined. But it's true that they're in conflict: one says "well you're already using three guards, so this won't hurt" and the other says "you should be using fewer guards". All that said, if you're talking about guards, you should be pointing to http://freehaven.net/anonbib/#wpes12-cogs rather than http://freehaven.net/anonbib/#ccs2013-usersrouted

Comment: @Roger: Thanks. I think that I'll just wait for Ian Goldberg's group to respond to Johnson et al. (2013).