# Looking for Conflux code

Tags: configuration, relays, circuit, performance

I'm looking for source code of Conflux tool, published [here](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/techreports/2013/cacr2013-16.pdf).

There's statement: 'We implemented the multipath construction and cell sequencing,
buffering, and reordering in the Tor source code (version 0.2.3.0-alpha-dev).'

Unfortunately, I didn't found version like that.

There is a [post](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/201/is-it-possible-to-team-multiple-circuits-in-the-current-tor-network?newreg=cf33515883e742f6bed51d7dfa11b49d) discuss about it, but no code attached.

Does someone know something more about it?